# How can I compare tuples using MySQL?

Tags: sql, comparison, tuples, mysql-workbench

one more problem. I need your help.

Make a list of medications that have been entered as the same (identical_with) but differ in their association with the disease.

[image: same medications]identical_with

[image: different association]association

I don't know how to do that.

The result should be in that case:

[image]result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to use twice the table association. Following code should be OK:

```
select
    i.Name_1, i.Name_2
from
    association a
inner join
    identical_with i
    on i.Name_1 = a.Name
inner join
    association a2
    on i.Name_2 = a2.Name
where
    a2.Fachname <> a1.Fachname
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment, although the answer is essentially "you can't do this in MySQL".

The support you are looking for is for hierarchical or recursive queries.  Almost every databases except MySQL has built-in support for these types of queries.  This leaves you with essentially four choices:

- Switch to using a database that has such support.  Among free databases, these include Postgres, SQL Server Express, and Oracle Express.
- If you limit the depth of equivalence, you can use [repeated self joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query).
- You can do this with a while loop in a stored procedure.  However, that is not a single SQL statement.
- Use a [nested set model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
- Use a method where you store the full path.

Unfortunately, the last two methods require triggers to maintain the data structure of inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Gordon. But if you look above, you'll see a solution which works fine. Cedric didn't use a nested set model or repeated self joins. All you need to do the task was to use two inner joins and a 2nd table. Maybe you could show me your solution, it might be helpful.

Comment: @user2379123 . . . That works one layer deep.  It  does not work for traversing the identical links more than one level.